# JavaScript Alert on Check-box Loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a problem in my code.

I want to write a code of java alert while checkbox is not checked.

I have a loop of checkboxes

here is code

```
 <?php 
 for ($i=0; $i<count($chk); $i++) {

 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='pr' value=''/>".$chk[$i];
 echo "</br>";

 }
?>
```

and here is JavaScript

```
<script>

var tags = document.getElementsByName('pr'),
    value = '', i = 0;

for( ; i < pr.length; i++ )
{
    if( pr[i].checked=='' ) {

alert("Please Check All Checkboxes");
    }
}
    </script>
```

**I want that the checkbox which are echo from loop is all checked then is proceed it to next page. If anyone checkbox is not checked it show an alert message**

> Problem:
>   If i am not checked anyone checkbox it proceed, and i want it would not proceed if anyone checkbox is not checked

Comment: What exactly is the "Problem that you are having?"

Comment: @NSNoob i update my question with problem

Comment: Good however might I suggest that it could be rephrased to be more clear? Something "Currently, If I haven't checked a checkbox, it proceeds ahead. I want to stop it from that if any checkbox is unchecked."

Answer (score 2):

```
var allAreChecked = true;
for( ; i < pr.length; i++ )
{
    if( pr[i].checked=='' ) {

        allAreChecked = false;
    }
}
if (!allAreChecked) {
    alert("Please Check All Checkboxes");
}
```

Or,

```
var allAreChecked = true;
for( ; i < pr.length; i++ )
{
    if( pr[i].checked=='' ) {

        alert("Please Check All Checkboxes");
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, more concisely, and legibly:

```
function checked(element) {
    return element.prop('checked');
}
if (!Array.prototype.every(tags, checked)) {
    alert("Please Check All Checkboxes");
}
```

EDIT: proof it works:

```js
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var pr = document.getElementsByName('pr'),
      i = 0;

  var allAreChecked = true;
  for( ; i < pr.length; i++ )
  {
    if( pr[i].checked=='' ) {
      allAreChecked = false;
    }
  }
  if (!allAreChecked) {
    alert("Please Check All Checkboxes");
  } else {
    alert("All OK");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='pr' value=''/>
<input type='checkbox' name='pr' value=''/>
<input type='checkbox' name='pr' value=''/>
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

Comment: Which one? Where? How? Is there an error message? What is it doing that you don't want, or what is it not doing that you do? "Its not working" is the most unhelpful comment possible.

Comment: @Amadan : for loop `for( ; i < pr.length; i++ )`

Comment: @Amadan Same problem i face If I haven't checked a checkbox, it proceeds ahead. I want to stop it from that if any checkbox is unchecked

Comment: It works. You are messing up with the code while copy pasting.